# Calculating the difference between the output of two class objects

Tags: python, django

I have created two class objects that retrieve information from a database and store them in pandas in order for me to use the data science libraries. They both return values that I display in a Django template. I want to create a third value that is just the calculated difference of the first two and also display that in the Django template.

First class object:

```
class IntDailyNumbers (object):
    def __init__(self, begin_date, end_date, store=None):
        self.begin_date = begin_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.store = store
        self.int_daily_numbers = pd.DataFrame(list(gapayment.objects.values('Trans_Store', 'Fee_Pd', 'Trans_date')))
        self.int_daily_numbers['Fee_Pd'] = pd.to_numeric(self.int_daily_numbers['Fee_Pd'])
        self.int_daily_numbers['Trans_date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.int_daily_numbers['Trans_date'])
        self.sum_int_daily_numbers = np.sum(self.int_daily_numbers[(self.int_daily_numbers['Trans_date'] >=self.begin_date) &
                                                               (self.int_daily_numbers['Trans_date'] <= self.end_date) &
                                                               (self.int_daily_numbers['Trans_Store'] == self.store.store_number)])
    def get_sum_int_daily_numbers(self):
        sum_intdailynumbers = self.sum_int_daily_numbers['Fee_Pd']
        sum_intdailynumbers = round(sum_intdailynumbers.astype(float), 3)
        return sum_intdailynumbers

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_sum_int_daily_numbers()
```

Second Class Object:

```
class IntDailyGoals (object):
    def __init__(self, begin_date, end_date, store=None):
        self.begin_date = begin_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.store = store
        #print(self.begin_date, self.end_date, self.store.store_number)
        self.int_mnth_goal = pd.DataFrame(list(StoreGoalsInput.objects.values('store_number',
                                                                          'interest',
                                                                          'date')))
        self.int_mnth_goal['interest'] = pd.to_numeric(self.int_mnth_goal['interest'])
        self.int_mnth_goal['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.int_mnth_goal['date'])
        self.mnth_goal_int =self.int_mnth_goal[(self.int_mnth_goal['date'] >= self.begin_date) &
                                           (self.int_mnth_goal['date'] <= self.end_date) &
                                           (self.int_mnth_goal['store_number'] == self.store.store_number)]
        self.mnth_goal_int= self.mnth_goal_int['interest']
        self.tot_workingdays = np.busday_count(np.datetime64(self.begin_date),
                                           np.datetime64(self.end_date),
                                           weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')
        self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays = round(np.divide(self.mnth_goal_int, self.tot_workingdays),2)


    def get_div_goalsint_wdays(self):
        div_goalsint_wdays = self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays.tolist()[0]
        return div_goalsint_wdays

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_div_goalsint_wdays()
```

I believe I need to make a third class for the difference calculation but I cannot figure out how to pass the returns of the first two.

Comment: Your classes are named identical `IntDailyGoals`?

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the class names.

Answer (score 0):

How I understand your question, it has nothing to do with django, but with passing objects from one class to another. Here are two simple solutions, given by `class C` and `class D`.

First lets define a minimal example of your two classes. Both have a method, that does something and returns something.

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
        return 'foo'

class B:
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')
        return 'bar'
```

---

Solution 1: We create a third class, that has an instance of type A and an instance of type B as member variable.

```
# Contains a class instance of A and B and baz() accesses their methods.
class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def baz(self):
        self.a.foo()
        self.b.bar()
```

You can use this class with:

```
# main
a = A()
b = B()

c = C(a,b)
c.baz()
```

---

Solution 2: We simply pass the two return values to the function `qux()`. This function can also be part of a class, if you want it to be.

```
class D:
    def qux(self, res_a, res_b):
        print(res_a, res_b)
```

Here we can use `qux()` in the following way

```
# main
a = A()
b = B()

d = D()
d.qux(a.foo(),b.bar())
```

---

Since there was some confusion about inheritance. You can also inherit the methods. Don't confuse this with Solution 1. And I don't advise to use inheritance here.  The idea of inheritance is, that a child class object `is-a` parent-class object, like a square is-a rectangle. And that is not what you want.

```
class E(A,B):
    def foobar(self):
        self.foo()
        self.bar()
```

Usage from main:

```
e = E()
e.foobar()
```

Comment: I would agree and in the future I will make sure to only tag what I am referencing. So the solution is to use class multi-inheritance to create a third class that captures the returns from the 1st and 2nd, then create a fourth class to actually do the difference calculation?

Comment: No, this solution has nothing to do with inheritance, since nothing is inherited. Solution 1:  `class C` contains an instance of type `A` and `B` and has access to their functions via `self.a.foo()`.  Solution 2: The method `qux` of  `class D` gets the return values as arguments.

Comment: @Prof.Falken : I have edited the answer. This should be better understandable now.

Comment: I believe I understand. I will try this and update you on how it went. Thanks for your time and explaining it so well!

Comment: @Prof.Falken, you can also [Try it online](https://tio.run/##dZDNDoMgEITvPAU3JUEuvTXpQa3PQUAxNTFqkB7al7e7gvWnlotkdhm/meHlHn13maayVeNI0yuhcCpT07rv49G0NfMSnsE2nYsjmETsK1rjnrajs0qIt8lWG63sHxuYnNigutjkq42UTdc4KWcvThWneuOIolD0RtVe0iBpsmF5H1n8S4Fh2eGtQHS2sNy3zeiAYc0olf/on4C74WJTxCnP2K7lk4ZmgDMmT4RJU7hgvGxGhEseKw7/KQWmZCSUnCQJlEwqWLiDWgmED3l5iAjz3baB5QKWjQh0jEzTBw)

Comment: This worked great! Took me a few tries but I got the syntax down. Thanks for also explain instance vs inheritance. Thanks for your help!